# When can we use the integral test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was going over my notes and I found that I wrote that we **cannot** use the integral test on the following series, why is that?
$$
\sum \frac{5}{k^2 \ln(k)}
$$
Isn't it both decreasing and positive? Aren't those the conditions for an integral test?

Thank you

;)

Comment: Have you tried integrating it? How did that go?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you meant
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac5{k^2\ln{(k)}}$$
then of course we can use the integral test as stated. We have that
$$0\lt\int_3^\infty\frac5{x^2\ln{(x)}}\mathrm{d}x\lt\int_3^\infty\frac5{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac53$$
and hence the sum is convergent. (I use the lower bound $3$ because we require $\ln{(x)}\gt1$ for the inequality to hold)

Comment: (+1) After seeing @Arthur's comment this was my thought also! However, I suspect Author's comment explains why the note was written in the first place, and it's the note itself that is a bit ambiguous (as your answer shows). In fact, I'd skip the integral test and just use direct comparison with an appropriate (multiple of a) $p$-series, and maybe the instructor said this but it didn't get written down in the OP's notes.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I believe the OP thought the integral test could not be used because the associated integral does not have a nice closed form. As you say, comparison with $5/k^2$ is a better approach for this question in my opinion.

Comment: OK, I'm done editing my comment! (When you wrote $5/k^2,$ I realized that "direct comparison with a $p$-series" wasn't exactly correct.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can clearly apply the integral test here. You can also do without it:

Let
$$
\forall n \ge2,\, u_n = \frac{5}{n^2\ln(n)} \quad \text{ and } \quad v_n = \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
We have
$$
\forall n \ge 2,\, \frac{u_n}{v_n} = \frac{5}{\ln(n)}
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{u_n}{v_n} = 0
$$
So
$
u_n = o(v_n)
$
and since $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ are positive, and $\sum_{n \ge 2}v_n$ is convergent,
$$
\sum_{n\ge2}u_n \text{ is convergent.}
$$